# Adding UIWebView to UIAlertView iOS

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uialertview

I have successfully added `UIWebView` to `UIAlertView` and displayed Html page in alert pop-up.
But now I want to keep track of elements present in `UIWebView`. So can you please tell me how can I come to know which `UIButton` is clicked in `UIWebView` displayed in `alert` pop-up window?

Code:

```
NSString *html =@"<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><form action=\"action_page.php\">First name:<br><input type=\"text\" name=\"firstname\"><br>        Last name:<br>        <input type=\"text\" name=\"lastname\"><br><br>    <input type=\"submit\">        </form>                <p>Note that the form itself is not visible.</p>     <p>Also note that the default width of a text field is 20 characters.</p>        </body>        </html>";

UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
[webView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,200,400)];
NSData *data = [html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[webView loadData:data MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"]];
webView.delegate = self;

UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"TEST" message:@"subview" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
[av setValue:webView forKey:@"accessoryView"];
[av show];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding that web view you need to set delegate to the current view controller from which the alert is being present. So in the `web view delegate` method you will be able to track the click events using the `javascript query`.

you can fetch that in `web view` methods:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
        //javascrip evalution code
}
```

Comment: I have added UIWebView to UIALertView using syntax :
    
    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"TEST" message:@"subview" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
    [av setValue:webView forKey:@"accessoryView"];
    [av show];

Comment: yes so to that UIviewWeb you can give delegate to the current view.

Comment: Add the same code to your question to make it more clear. and you can set delegate to  `webView.delegate = self`  and add protocol for the webview. may be that solve your click events.

Comment: I have created a UIWebView object and html string is loaded in webview and then I have added this web-view in alert using [setValue forKey].Now I have track which button is being clicked in webview which is displayed in alert